# Quicker way to write functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, repeat, innerhtml

I am working on a javascript app which displays images of the results of different US elections.
I am thinking there must be a quicker way to do this than what I am doing. There must be some way I can have one function that displays an election map with the year as a parameter, but how can I do this with image variables? I am trying to think of a quicker way to write this code. If anyone knows, please help me out.

```
<script>

var el2020img = "<img src=270towin.png width=600 height=300>";
var el2016img = "<img src=201019164452-2016-election-map.jpg width=600 height=300>";



function the2020election(){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=el2020img;
}
function the2016election(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=el2016img;
}
</script>
```

I am wondering about how to do this.

Comment: Something like `function theElection(selector, content) { document.getElementById(selector).innerHtml=content }`?

Comment: [Create an object](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) that holds both images, then just [access them](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors). You don’t need two separate functions and you don’t need two separate variables.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use an object indexed by year, whose values are the filenames associated with the year.

```
const srcs = {
  2020: '270towin.png',
  2016: '201019164452-2016-election-map.jpg'
};
```

And then, instead of having multiple standalone functions, have a single function that takes the year as an argument.

```
const demo = document.getElementById("demo");
const populate = (year) => {
  demo.innerHTML = `<img src="${srcs[year]}" width=600 height=300>`;
};
```

A nicer way would be to rename the images so that they all have a consistent format, such as `2016.png` and `2020.png`. Then the object becomes unnecessary, and you could do

```
const populate = (year) => {
  demo.innerHTML = `<img src="${year}.png" width=600 height=300>`;
};
```

Comment: You can also avoid `innerHTML` by using `demo.replaceChildren(Object.assign(document.createElement("img"), { src: srcs[year], width: 600, height: 300 }));`. Not totally necessary to do in this small case, but useful to know in general. Alternatively, the `<img>` element can stay the same and then only the `src` property needs to be altered.

Comment: thanks for your help. I don't understand why you use const populate = (year) rather than populate(year)?

Comment: @JosephFoley See [`const`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) and [Arrow function expressions](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). `populate(year)` by itself would be invalid syntax. If you mean `function populate(year){`…`}`, this is the old, pre-ES6 way of defining functions which lacks a few advantages and has a few problems that the modern approaches get right.

Comment: Yeah, you can use a `function` instead if you want, arrow functions everywhere are just my preference.

Comment: Also, ,how can I call this function after an "onclick"?

Comment: @JosephFoley `someElement.addEventListener('click', () => populate(2016))` or, even better, add only a single event listener to a parent element and use a data attribute or the text content on the button to identify what image to insert

Comment: Thanks for your help. This works but only on a double click. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: nevermind, I figured it out now